# Do I need to copy a block passed into a GCD block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

Do I need to copy the blocks *requestSuccessBlock(data) / requestFailureBlock(error)* to the heap, the ones that are passed as params to the GCD function *dispatch_async(queue, block)* in the following code : -

```
//NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL method here
[[_urlSession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            requestSuccessBlock(data);
        });

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            requestFailureBlock(error);
        });
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "do I need to copy the block"? Are you talking about the memory semantics of the `requestSuccessBlock` block? (If that's the question, no explicit "copy" or "Block_copy" is needed on your part as all of that is taken care of for you.) Or are you talking about your calling of two different blocks, the success and failure blocks? I'm unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that `dataTaskWithUrl:completionHandler:` will Block_copy() the block literal that you are passing.

Blocks are themselves reference counted objects.  As such the `completionHandler` block will maintain a reference to them so you do not need to do any manual memory management, even though I assume you have declared `requestSuccessBlock` and `requestFailureBlock` as locals in the enclosing scope.

I do think it's odd you're invoking both success and failure blocks in the completion, but I assume this is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Is requestSuccessBlock copied on the heap by GCD or the method - dataTaskWithUrl:completionHandler: ?

Comment: The `dispatch_async` and `dataTaskWithUrl:completionHandler: ` both copy the block, that you send as a parameter, from stack to heap.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the completion block like a closure. It will capture the whole context of the method the completion handler has been passed from.

No, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

When a block is copied, it retains all captured variables of pointer-to-object type, and does a block copy on all captured variables of pointer-to-block type. `requestSuccessBlock` and `requestFailureBlock` are variables of pointer-to-block type which are captured by that big block that is passed to `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`. So the question really boils down to, do you need to copy the block that is passed to `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:`.

Memory management rules are generally local. That means, you don't need to know (and shouldn't care) about what another method does, for you to use memory management correctly in your own method. Since the `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` method takes the block in a parameter of pointer-to-block type, if it needs to store the block around for later asynchronous use, it must copy it (we can guess that it is asynchronous by its name in this case, but we don't need to know this). As far as the calling method is concerned, it doesn't matter if the method uses the block synchronously or asynchronously; it just needs to ensure the block is valid when passed, and the rest is the called method's responsibility.

Since your own method is not itself storing the blocks for use later, the answer is **No**, you don't need to copy them.